# Estimation of a Weibull distribution. Overview of the methods

Tags: distributions, fitting, weibull-distribution

I'm looking for a method to estimate the parameters of a Weibull distribution from a given set of data. I know there are several method in literature, but I couldn't understand very well the differences. I also inherited a piece of code that does it, but the method adopted seems to be different from all the other I've seen (even if not too much).

Looking around I found the following methods:

- **Maximum likelihood estimation** This seems to me the best method that can be adopted. On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Maximum_likelihood), however, two different version of the MLE for the Weibull distribution appear: one using all the samples and one using only the N largest samples. Which one is better? How do I choose N?
- **Method of Moments** This, as far as I've understood seems superseded by MLE. Right?
- **Graphical method** How reliable is this method? Should I prefer the MLE over it? I also found several ways to estimate the values of $Y_i = F(x_i)$. Some suggest to use $i/(N+1)$ where $i$ is the index of the sample and $N$ is the total number of samples. I also found however $(i-0.3)/(N+0.4)$ and $(i-0.5)/N$. Which one should I use? Which is the difference?

Lastly, in the code I inherited, the author adopted an even different strategy, similar to the graphical method.

- He used the data to compute the estimated cumulative density function in order to know $\tilde{Y} = F(X)$ and then fitted this function with a straight line (using the same normalization used in the graphical method) to estimate the parameters. Is this equivalent to the graphical method with $Y_i = i/(n+1)$ ?

Thank you very much

Comment: $i / (N + i)$ looks like a typo for $i / (N + 1)$.